# Average and sort by this based on other conditional columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table in SQL Server 2017 like below:

```
Name  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4
Jack  null    1     1      3
Mark  null    3     2      2
John  null    2     3      1
```

What I need to do is to add an average rank column then rank those names based on those scores. We ignore null ranks. Expected output:

```
Name  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4  AvgRank FinalRank
Jack  null    1     1      3       1.66    1
Mark  null    3     2      2       2.33    3
John  null    2     3      1       2       2
```

My query now looks like this:

```
;with cte as (
   select *, AvgRank= (Rank1+Rank2+Rank3+Rank4)/@NumOfRankedBy
   from mytable
)
select *, FinakRank= row_number() over (order by AvgRank)
from cte
```

I am stuck at finding the value of @NumOfRankedBy, which should be 3 in our case because `Rank1` is `null` for all.

What is the best way to approach such an issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conumdrum stems from the fact your table in not normalised and you are treating data (Rank) as structure (columns).

You should have a table for Ranks where each rank is a *row*, then your query is easy.

You can *unpivot* your columns into rows and then make use of *avg*

```
select *, FinakRank = row_number() over (order by AvgRank)
from mytable
cross apply (
  select Avg(r * 1.0) AvgRank
  from (values(rank1),(rank2),(rank3),(rank4))r(r)
)r;
```